# Colored section title fails with [leftmargin] option of titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I want my section title colored. It's all right when I use `\titleformat` from the package `titlesec` to set it.

But when I add the option argument `[leftmargin]`, the title text fails to change color. 
Is something wrong with my code?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\thesection.}
{1em}
{}
\section{my colored section}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]% only the optional argument "leftmargin" added
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\thesection.}
{1em}
{}
\section{The Color Unchanged}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A work-around: put the colour command in the 2nd and 4th arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{,xcolor, titlesec}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\thesection.}
{1em}
{}
\section{my colored section}

\titleformat{\section}[leftmargin]% only the optional argument "leftmargin" added
{\normalfont\bfseries}
{\color{blue}\thesection.}
{1em}
{\color{blue}}
\section{The Color Unchanged}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this can solve my problem. But I think this is only a temparory solution. Is this a problem of titlesec? Is there a final solution?

Comment: One should take a look at the code for the leftmargin option.

Comment: Oh, I think this is too hard for me.